# In Pathfinder's Advanced Race Guide's Race creator, what does the prerequisite for Advanced ability scores mean?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, races

> Advanced (4 RP)
>
> Prerequisites: Advanced or monstrous power level.
>
> Modifiers: Pick either mental or physical ability scores. Members of this race gain a +2 bonus to all of those scores, a +4 bonus to one score of the other type, and a –2 penalty to one other ability score of the other type.

I have looked around but I can't find out precisely what the Prerequisite is checking for.  Can someone explain?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! I don't know the answer here, but it's definitely an interesting question. If you haven't, it's worthwhile to take a look at the [Tour], and when you get 20 rep, feel free to join us in the [Chat]!

Answer (score 5):

It is a reference to the Power Level of the race on 214 of the same book.

> There are three power levels: standard, advanced, and monstrous. Standard races can only take standard racial traits, while advanced races can take both standard and advanced racial traits, and monstrous races can take standard, advanced, and monstrous racial traits.

All of the races presented in the book that are meant to be played as PCs are Standard. There are, however, other races in places like the Bestiary that are significantly more powerful, Monstrous. There are guidelines for creating both, and ones in the middle, Advanced, though you see the fewest Advanced.

Answer (score 1):

The race builder is broken into levels of power, Standard, Advanced, and Monstrous, based on the number of RP they receive.  This is on page 214 of the ARG, and is intended to serve as a measure of how powerful the race is.  It limits the numbers of traits in a single category the race can be given, and also serves as a prerequisite for trait choices like Advanced Ability Scores.